# Get access to posted values in custom modelbinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently I have an `IActionFilter` that accepts a `List<T>` as parameter. In that action method I examine the posted viewmodel values. It looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SavePage(List<BaseField> fields)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
    {
        if (fields[i].Type == "bb")
        {
            var inputObj = new InputConfigViewModel();
            await TryUpdateModelAsync(inputObj, $"fields[{i}]");
        }
        if (fields[i].Type == "ee")
        {
            var tObj = new TextareaConfigViewModel();
            await TryUpdateModelAsync(tObj, $"fields[{i}]");
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

This works so far. But I would like to abstract this code away to a custom `ModelBinder` class.

```
public class BaseFieldModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Need access to "List<BaseField> fields"...

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

How can I get access the `List<BaseField> fields` values in my `ModelBinder`, like I can from the action method in my `Controller`?

Answer (score 1):

Custom model binders work on objects and not generic lists. You cannot access the all list inside the binder, but you can access each individual object.

With this said, I don't believe you can abstract the code, because you don't have the `ControllerContext` you need to access the `FormCollection` inside the binder context, neither to execute the `TryUpdateModelAsync` call in order to get extra information from form post that is not present on the `List<BaseField>`. You just have the ModelBindingContext.

If you still want to try, you have a good working example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding).

Here is the relevant part, where you can get the reference of the object:

```
// Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
{
    return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
}

bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

// Check if the argument value is null or empty
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    return TaskCache.CompletedTask;
}
```